# Life of Request Headers Variable after post backs

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, httprequest

i making a post call to `Asp.net` Page via `Cross platform`, Passing some variables in header part, Request succeeded and page Rendered.

if any control on the page causes a `Postback` and page submitted to itself then,

Will previous `Post` call headers variables are there after `PostBack`

Comment: Did you mean Cross Page Postback instead of Cross platform?

Comment: If you can, please provide some sample code. However, I believe the answer is NO, request headers won't be available in future postbacks.

Comment: @PabloRomeo,only first Call is cross platform, sorry for confusion

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to by saying "Cross platform". Could you describe that further and provide some code?

Comment: a call from php to load aspnet page in New Window.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, no, request headers will not persist so you will have to place that data in viewstate or session during Load if !IsPostBack or something like that, I think.

Comment: thanks, yes i applied this approach, but can post variable are still persist which came in first call ?